# How to make big emoticons for facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, emoticons

Is it really possible? i have seen lots of my friends sending me big emoticons via facebook chat messages. How they do this??

Comment: Wow... Really? You are asking it in StackOverflow? (I don't think it has nothing to do with codes IMO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. go to http://apps.facebook.com/big-emo-creator , select an image and wait few seconds till the app process your image and give you the code.

But these emoticons are not much useful as you have to remember a huge code to use this emos. However you can give it a try.